# dynamic table height exceeds page height

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-grid

I have a section that has a grid in it which is distributed as follows (or at least that is what I'm trying to get):

[image]

Now, Inside the calculation grid, I insert a dynamic table that has 6 columns but an unknown number of rows where are based on the amount of data in the JSON that I load.

My problem is, that in case there are many rows, the height of the calculation_grid changes and I can't figure out why (I used height:100% and the table is inside that parent from my understanding).

What I get is:

[image]

What I want to get is (managed to get it only by setting max-height:750px, but I don't want to use a static number, I just want it to fill its parent, calculation_grid and that it will be fixed):

[image]

The HTML I'm using is:

```
<section id="optimizer">
    <h1 id="optimizer_title">Test</h1>
    <div class="calculation-grid-container">
        <div class="current_status_grid">
            <h2>Current</h2>
            <h3>Level: </h3>
            <h3>XP: </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="goal_grid">
            <h2>Enter your goal</h2>
            <h3>Level: </h3>
            <h3>XP: </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="calculation_grid">
            <ul class="responsive-table">
                <li class="table-header">
                    {% for cell in headings %}
                    <div class="col"> {{ cell }}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </li>
                {% for row in data %}
                <li class="table-row">
                    {% for cell in row %}
                    <div class="col"> {{ cell }}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The CSS:

```
section {
  background-image: url('icons/background_main.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.95;
}

section .calculation-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 90%;
  height: 75%;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.current_status_grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  column-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.goal_grid {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  column-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.calculation_grid {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  column-gap: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 7;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}


/**************/

/* DATA TABLE */

/**************/

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.responsive-table {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height:750px;
}

.responsive-table li {
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: 10fr 10fr 10fr 20fr 20fr 30fr;
  justify-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive-table .table-header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.9);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.responsive-table .table-row {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.9);
}

@media all and (max-width: 100%) {
  .responsive-table .table-header {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive-table li {
    display: block;
  }
  .responsive-table .col {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You set height to 75% but 75% of what? Is there more styling e.g. of section or body or something which limits the height?

Comment: 75% of the section, that's what I at least tried to get. Added section style to the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want. First, you should probably be using a [table tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) for accessibility. In terms of scrolling the key is to set the section to have a height of 100vh (vh stands for view height) and to set a overflow on the tbody (this way your headers will stay locked so users dont forget what column they're looking at). If you just do height 100% all over the place the page will just keep expanding  due to the content and that means what 100% evaluates to just keeps getting bigger and bigger. To get the scroll there needs to be at least *one* hard stop somewhere. Hence the 100vh on your section, ensuring it will take up the full viewport height.

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
}
section .calculation-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 90%;
  height: 75%;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.current_status_grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  column-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.goal_grid {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  column-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.calculation_grid {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  column-gap: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 7;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

tbody {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}


/**************/


/* DATA TABLE */


/**************/

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.responsive-table {
/*   overflow-y: scroll; */
  width: 100%;
/*   height: auto; */
/*   max-height: 750px; */
}

tbody tr td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.responsive-table li {
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: 10fr 10fr 10fr 20fr 20fr 30fr;
  justify-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive-table .table-header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.9);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.responsive-table .table-row {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.9);
}

@media all and (max-width: 100%) {
  .responsive-table .table-header {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive-table li {
    display: block;
  }
  .responsive-table .col {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="optimizer">
  <h1 id="optimizer_title">Test</h1>
  <div class="calculation-grid-container">
    <div class="current_status_grid">
      <h2>Current</h2>
      <h3>Level: </h3>
      <h3>XP: </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="goal_grid">
      <h2>Enter your goal</h2>
      <h3>Level: </h3>
      <h3>XP: </h3>
    </div>
    <table class="calculation_grid">
      <thead>
      <tr class="responsive-table">
        <th class="table-header">
          for cell in headings
          <div class="col"> cell </div>
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="col">
            hey there
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </d>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey mate, thank you for the answer. I updated my question so you could see the CSS for my section. It is 100vh in it. I tried to change to table and implement it but I get the same result, it seems like it changes the dimension of the section.

Comment: hmmm.... try adding `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;` to `calculation-grid-container` and adding `height:100%` and `overflow: scroll` to the `tbody` that should get you the rest of the way i think